# yum clean all: cannot use yum on RHEL 7

Tags: linux, installation, yum, rhel

I was facing an installation issue with yum which couldn't find mirrors for php.
Hence i performed

```
yum clean all
```

and when i tried to install again, it gave me the following error.

Not sure what to do. I am working on RHEL 7.

```
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
file:///mnt/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /mnt/repodata/repomd.xml"
Trying other mirror.


 One of the configured repositories failed (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.6),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=InstallMedia ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable InstallMedia
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=InstallMedia

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=InstallMedia.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from InstallMedia: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
file:///mnt/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#37 - "Couldn't open file /mnt/repodata/repomd.xml"
```

How to i get this working again

Comment: Have you changed you yum config at all or anything related since this error came along? Have you actually checked the path show is valid for that repo file?

Comment: The repo file doesnt exist anymore. I did not make any changes in configs as well.

Comment: what is in your `/etc/yum.repos.d` and `/mnt/repodata` folders?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a repo configured that no longer exists.

The repo will be configured in a file in /etc/yum.repos.d/ or directly in /etc/yum.conf
Look in both locations for the repo that used to be under /mnt

If you disable or delete the missing repo ‘yum clean all’ should work again.

My assumption is that at some point you used the repo on the install media to install some packages and that install media is no longer mounted.

If you want use the install media again you need to remount it on the exact path it was mounted on. i.e. /mnt

You might also like to look at the man page for yum-config-manager if it is installed as another way to list and disable repos.